# Android Thread seems not to work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

in a tuner application on which I am working right now, I wanted to implement an Indicator which shows if the right pitch is played. For this I have implemented that the color of the indicator only changes when I hold the pitch for atleast 2 seconds.

```
    public void thr(final double v1, final double v2) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            int i = 0;
            while (pitchInHz >= v1 && pitchInHz < v2) {
                if(i == 20){    //2 Sekunden
                    imageView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(holo_green_light));
                }else {
                    imageView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(darker_gray));
                    try {
                        sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
            running = false;
        }
    }.start();
```

Everytime my application tries to use the thread, the app just crashes.
some ideas why this is happening?

```
        if(pitchInHz >= 72.41 && pitchInHz < 92.41) {
        //e
        noteText.setText("e"); //this is working
        if(!running) {
            thr(72.41, 92.41);
            running = true;
        }
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Why is the background thread even necessary? Clearly this could be done in a more reliable way??

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing it's because you're trying to access a view from a different thread than the main thread, which you cannot do such thing.

Try running like this:

```
public void thr(final double v1, final double v2) {
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        int i = 0;
        while (pitchInHz >= v1 && pitchInHz < v2) {
            if(i == 20){    //2 Sekunden
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @override
                    public void run() {
                        imageView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(holo_green_light));
                    }
                })

            }else {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @override
                    public void run() {
                        imageView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(darker_gray));
                    }
                })
                try {
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        running = false;
    }
}.start();
```